# Layout in Android emulator looks different from what is shown on the the layout editor

Tags: android

In the layout editor, I am using Pixel 2 as shown below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeTlj.jpg

The problem is in the layout editor, there is still some space between the TextView and the bottom of the screen but in the emulator, there is no space. If the TextView gets longer, it will still be visible in the layout editor but in the emulator, some text at the bottom will get cut off. The emulator is also Pixel 2 so shouldn't it look the same as the layout in the layout editor?

Here is the emulator
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6np2Z.png

Below is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/header" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/poster"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/poster" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="Beauty and the Beast"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:tint="#ff8c00"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.96" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="March 2019 PG 129 minutes"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="RENT FROM $29.99"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="BUY FROM 129.99"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="start"
                android:tint="#fa2a5b"
                app:fabSize="auto"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/tomato" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/belowfab1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="242 ratings"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/belowfab2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Family"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/belowfab3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="71%"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/belowfab4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Similar"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/belowfab1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/story"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="The story and character you know and love come to spectacular life in the live action adaption of Disney's animated classic Beauty and the Beast."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider2" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have no idea why it looks different, can anyone enlighten me cuz this is not the first time I encountered this problem.

Comment: You should not rely on it looking 100% the same. There are a few things that can affect the looks in the real app. For example, there's a "text size" option in phone settings, where they can opt to increase the font. There's a similar option for zooming in other things too, increasing them in size, forgot what it's called. Also on smaller phones the longer text won't fit either. So you need to wrap this into a scrollable parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because on layout editor there is no status, action and bottom navigation bar but on emulator it is there. If you want to verify, then try with full screen theme with no action and navigation bar on screen.

Second, try to avoid more use of guideline as currently this layout is so complex, you can define it in more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

The app's layout will reflect differently on different devices because each device has a different screen size and in your layout file, there is also an option to choose the screen size. You can use `margin_bottom` in `TextView` to reduce the error. But it mainly depends on the screen size of the device. You can also use `NestedScrollView` to reflect your design on the maximum screen.